# Debug paging library from Architecture components

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2, android-architecture-components, android-paging-library

are there any way that help to debug **paging** library from architecture components with network requests, as if there are any error in parsing the `JSON` response, the library fails and return empty list but it doesn't give any indicator in which class the parsing fails

Comment: https://www.coroutinedispatcher.com/2019/07/manage-network-states-with-paging.html?source=post_page-----911445edc21e----------------------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have discovered that helped me to know in which class the parsing `exception` occurs is it's depends on the way you call the api with `retrofit` if you just doing normal call then surround it with `try` and `catch` if you doing the call with `rx-java` you can catch the `exception` in `doOnError` or `onError`